# Which finite groups contain the two specific centralizers?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory

This is a question requiring the good knowledge of group theory:

> (Q1) Which finite groups $G$ contains some specific centralizers both of these two groups:
>
> i. the elementary group $Z_2^4$, and
>
> ii. the $D_4 \times Z_2$

-

> (Q2) Which finite groups $G$ ONLY contains specific centralizers isomorphic to these two groups (but contain NOTHING else):
>
> i. the elementary group $Z_2^4$, and
>
> ii. the $D_4 \times Z_2$

where $D_4$ is dihedral group with the order of $|D_4|=8$. Here $Z_2$ is the cyclic group of the order $|Z_2|=2$.

Let us consider the $|G|$ be as small as possible. **Your answer only needs** to provide just **AN example**, the **order** of the group |G| and its **all list of centralizers**. (NO need to be complete.) :o)

see also [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/759668/which-non-abelian-finite-groups-contain-the-two-specific-centralizers-part-ii).

Comment: see also this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/759668/which-non-abelian-finite-groups-contain-the-two-specific-centralizers-part-ii

Comment: For Q2: $D_4$ contains centralizers $D_4$, $Z_2\times Z_2$ and $Z_4$. If so, we are allowed to include the centralizers of $D_4 \times Z_2$ as $D_4 \times Z_2$, $Z_2 \times Z_2 \times Z_2$ and $Z_4 \times Z_2$.

Comment: SmallGroup(64,138) satisfies (Q1).

Comment: Thanks Derek, this is interesting. I have troubled to access GAP so I can only learn that: SmallGroup (64,138) = (((C4 x C2) : C2) : C2) : C2; but what is the form of this group? Can it be further decomposed by a direct product or semi-direct product of elementary groups, cyclic groups or Dihedral groups etc?

Comment: And what is the order of SmallGroup (64,138)? (the number of group elements?)

Comment: @ Derek, also what are all the centralizers of SmallGroup (64,138)? (there are 16 of them, correct?)

Comment: You should learn to do those calculations yourself in GAP.

Comment: I was trying GAP but I have trouble installing it. Sorry that if you can still fill in this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/760827/conjugacy-classes-and-centralizers-of-a-smallgroup

Comment: Please contact [GAP Support](http://www.gap-system.org/Contacts/trouble.html) to get some help with installing GAP. Describe your operating system and where the installation fails. For such computational questions the only way to proceed is to install it and learn yourself. As for the `SmallGroup(m,n)`, the 1st argument is the order of a group.